# .live is not a function error in rails 3.2.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am following [search-sort-using-ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast)

Here my gemfile includes

- rails 3.2.11
- sqlite-3
- will-paginate, '3.0'
- jquery-rails,'2.2.1'

Application.js file includes

> //= require jquery
>
> //= require jquery_ujs

script in application.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#products th a').live('click', function () {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
});
})
```

Error getting in console

```
$("#products th a").live is not a function
```

I searched but i didnt find any solution. can anyone help me what actual mistake i have done here

Thank you

Comment: which version of jquery are you using

Comment: Since `live()` is deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9, you should probably be using `on()`.

Comment: @jonathan: Am using jquery-rails,'2.2.1'. 
do i need to explicitly add jquery file again.

Comment: @rds: yea because, it also may depends on application.html or jquer-rails gem  also rite so

Comment: check your version by adding, alert($().jquery) in your javascript

Comment: @JonathandeM. hey yea its 1.9.1. I just changed it to .on instead of .live its working thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you're using jQuery 1.9, which removed [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (after it had been deprecated for several versions). You can get the same effect as `live` doing this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#products th a', function () {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

...which attaches the `click` handler to `document` but only fires it if the click started on or bubbled through an element matching the selector `#products th a` (which is what `live` did).

But `live` was deprecated and removed *for a reason* (a couple of them, actually), one of which being that it's almost never best to put the `click` handler all the way down at `document` (although it can be in very rare cases). Unless you're removing and recreating the `products` element, for instance, you'd probably want:

```
$(function () {
    $('#products').on('click', 'th a', function () {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

That tells jQuery to put the `click` handler on `#products`, but only fire it if the click event started on or bubbled through an element matching the `th a` selector.